# How to do fuzzy string matching?

Tags: python

I am trying to do an English dictionary and this is my code

```
import json
file = open("data.json", "r", encoding= "utf-8")

#data.json contains some words and meanings in English as a dict.

dictionary = json.loads(file.read())

word = input("Enter Word: ")

print(dictionary[word])
```

But also, if the user couldn't type correctly, I want to show near key in the dict.
(For example, if the user type runn, my code would be able to show that did you mean "run")
Is there any function to do that

Comment: Fuzzy matching, with e.g. https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/

Comment: If you are for security you could write it yourself with the difflib.SequenceMatcher. It's more fun that way and you are not relying on some PyPI package which could become malware

Comment: @DerSchinken Wow i don't know anything about the  difflib.SequenceMatcher. And also this problem given to search about kind of a homework. but thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Using `fuzzywuzzy`:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import json

file = open("data.json", "r", encoding= "utf-8")

dictionary = json.loads(file.read())

word = input("Enter Word: ")
if dictionary.get(word):
    print(dictionary[word])
else:
    possible_matches = sorted([k for k in dictionary.keys()], key=lambda x: fuzz.ratio(word, x))
    print(f"Did you mean {possible_matches[-1]}?") # Sorted in ascending order, so [-1] is best match.
    # Add whatever you want to do in this case.
```

Comment: The trick is to find the correct algorithm and fine-tune it.

Comment: i mean this library seems to be about 10000 easier to use than `Levenshtein`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic algorithm:

```py
dictionary = {"some word": "some meaning"}

def matches(words, searchPattern, constraint):
  similar = {}
  for i in range(constraint+1):
    similar[i] = []
  #print(similar)
  searchPattern = searchPattern.lower()
  for w in words:
    if abs(len(searchPattern) - len(w)) > constraint:
      continue
    #print(w, abs((abs(len(set(searchPattern).intersection(w))) - len(w))))
    if abs((abs(len(set(searchPattern).intersection(w))) - len(w))) <= constraint:
      similar[abs((abs(len(set(searchPattern).intersection(w))) - len(w)))].append(w)

  toRemove = []
  for key in list(similar.keys()):
    if similar[key] == []:
      toRemove.append(key)

  for key in toRemove:
    del similar[key]

  #print(similar)
  return similar


#Below is as an example.





#Note that the dictionary must be in lowercase for this program to work.
#Working example:
dictionary = {"stack": "some meaning", "overflow": "", "run": "", "python": "", "dictionary": ""}
constraint = 2 #How close the words have to be to the query to be considered

word = input("Word: ")
if word in dictionary.keys():
  print("That word is in the dictionary!")
else:
  result = matches(list(dictionary.keys()),  word, constraint)
  if len(list(result.keys())) <= 0:
    print("Sorry, that word was not found.")
  else:
    #Results are stored with the lower key being the most likely and the highest being the least likely.
    #For example:
    #  {0: ["abcd"], 1: ["abcde"], 2: ["fabcde", "abcdef"], 3: ["afbcedg"]}
    #would denote that abcd is the closest to the original word.
    string = ""
    length = len(result[list(result.keys())[0]][:-1])
    if length == 1 :
      string += result[list(result.keys())[0]][:-1][0] + " "
    else:
      for w in result[list(result.keys())[0]][:-1]:
        string += w + ", "
    string += ("" if len(list(result[list(result.keys())[0]])) == 1 else "or ") + result[list(result.keys())[0]][-1]
    print("Did you mean", string+"?")
```

Try running the program and experimenting with it. You may have to fine tune it. If necessary, I can explain how it works.

Comment: A little hard to understand, sorry.